PhpStorm как изменить \ убрать заливку в консоли?
Вывод ошибок происходит в виде 
И пока не выделишь сообщение, неясно что там написано. Как это исправить?

Посмотрите настройки Settings/Editor/Color scheme/Console colors
Уберите у нужного цвета Background или смените цвет


вот корректная настройка. на будущее

